# AJax won't submit into PHP form

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, forms

I would like to create a simple email subscription form, but not working yet. Here are steps that I want to do.

1. The validation is done using javascript code, if fail will alert popup error message.
2. Passing the input to MySQL database using AJAX and processing the form (server side) with PHP script.
3. If success, the .responseText will be printed on the document object.

Here is my code form code:

```
    <div class="header_resize">
      <div class="logo">
        <h1><img src="images/logo.jpg" width="235" height="59" /></h1>
      </div>
      <div class="subs-form">
      <p id="ajaxanswer"><b>Subscribe to our newsletter.</b></p>
      <script>
      <!--
function validateForm()
{
var x = document.forms["subscription"]["email"].value;
var atpos = x.indexOf("@");
var dotpos = x.lastIndexOf(".");
if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=x.length)
  {
  alert("Not a valid e-mail address");
  return false;
  }
else
{
function ajaxFunction() {
    var ajaxRequest;    //The variable that makes AJAX possible!
        try  {  
            ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
        }   catch (e)   {
        try  {
            ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        }   catch (e)   {
        try  {
            ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }   catch (e)   {
            alert ("Your Browser is not compatible!");
            return false;
            }
        }
    }   
// Function to receive data from server using  XMLHttpRequest object property  onreadystatechange
            // onreadystatechange stores function to process response from server
            ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
                // ajax.Request.readystate == 4 means the response is complete
                if (ajaxRequest.readystate == 4) {
                    // response.Text is whatever data returned by server
                    document.getElementByID('ajaxanswer').value = ajaxRequest.reponseText;
                }
            }
        var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
        var queryString = "?email=" + email;
        ajaxRequest.open("GET", "subscribe.php" + queryString, true);
        ajaxRequest.send(null);
}
}
}
//-->
</script>
      <form name="subscription">
          <input type="text" name="email">
          <input type="submit" onclick='validateForm()' value="Submit Your Email">
      </form>
      </div>
      <div class="clr"></div>
    </div>
```

and here is my php code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<?php

$conn=mysql_connect('localhost', 'dbuser', 'dbpwd') or die('Could not connect to MySql serve: ' . mysql_error());

mysql_select_db('dbname') or die('Could not select subscribe database: ' . mysql_error());

$safe_email = html_entity_decode($_GET['email']);

$sql="INSERT INTO subemail (email_addr) VALUES ('$safe_email')";

if (isset($_GET['email'])) {
    $failure = "There was an error when submitting the form!";
    $succeed = "Thank you for your subscription!";
    $subject = "Message Form - Email Subscription.";
    mail("my@email.com", $subject, "Email subscriber: " . $safe_email);
    echo $succeed;
    }
    else {
    echo $failure;
    }

mysql_close($conn);


?>
</body>
</html>
```

Anything wrong with the code?

Comment: Questions that do not ask about a [specific problem](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) are not a good fit for Stack Overflow. Specifically, if a question is asked in a way to provoke discussion or is subjective in general, it [should not be asked here](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask). If you have problems, eliminate them and ask about them, but just throwing down a lot of code with *"is this cool code?"* attached doesn't belong here.

Comment: where is id `ajaxanswer`? because you are calling it `document.getElementByID('ajaxanswer').` here

Comment: You don't need all that html tags in PHP code

Comment: @hanjaya check my answer, almost all your codes were misplaced, and had case problems

Comment: Before you get to far into learning mysql... The mysql_* functions are very old, insecure, and soon to be removed from PHP (as far as I've heard), try reading up on [PDO](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) or [MySQLi](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ref_mysqli.asp).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took me to remove some jiberish line of codes from your question, to make this work for you.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

    function subscribe(){
        var xmlhttp = false;

        if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }else{
            xmlhttp = ActiveXObject('Microsft.XMLHTTP');
        }


        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange  = function(){
           if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200){
                document.getElementById("ajaxanswer").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;     
            }
        }

        var email  = document.getElementById("email").value;
        xmlhttp.open('GET', 'subscribe.php?email='+email, true);
        xmlhttp.send(null); // important for Firefox -3.0
    } 

</script>
    <input type="text" id="email" name="email">
    <input type="submit" onclick='subscribe()'  value="Submit Your Email">  
<div id="ajaxanswer"></div>
```

Now, your subscribe.php file, should have the following PHP codes.

```
<?php

$email = $_GET['email'];
    if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
        echo 'invalid email';
    }else{
        echo 'your email is ok';
}
```

Comment: Hi php NoOb, Thanks for your replies. I will check this tomorrow at my workplace.

Comment: Is it better to validate the input on client or server side?

Comment: @hanjaya It does not really matter, because on subscribe.php you should get the value, and validate it, and since you are using Ajax, the page will not be refreshed, so there is no difference, infact, it is better to costumized the php page than the pop up javascript box. If you want me to add a simple php validation, I'll show you.

Comment: @hanjaya btw, if this answered helped you, don't forget to accept it:)

Comment: If you dont mind, can you post the php validation as well. I just did it but not successful.

Comment: @hanjaya Now check it. And tell me the result.

Comment: No messages appeared after inputting some invalid & valid email addresses.

Comment: I tested it in my PC, it works. Are you sure? can you try again?

Comment: Sorry, I said, put in in `subscript.php` I mean, to say put the PHP codes inside `subscribe.php` file

Comment: Thank you, I was wrapping the input fields with <form></form> before. As soon as I removed them, it works. Thank you so much!

Comment: Btw, just out of curiosity. Why it would not work when <form></form> wrap the inputs?

Comment: @hanjaya because, `<form>` is for submitting, input with the help of HTML. but, now everything is done with Ajax, and ajax has it's own posting attributes.

Comment: No Ob Thank you. Btw, if I would like to send using POST, what needs to be changed?

Answer (score 0):

Most of people don't use the old XMLHttpRequest since it is browser dependent. Try using a javascript framework such as jQuery. Ajax call is like 3 lines max. And try googling PHP jQuery Ajax. In the long run your project will be more manageable

Answer (score 0):

use jquery and ajax in your form page like this

```
$('form id goes here).submit(function(e){
e.preventDefault();

var assign_variable_name_to_field = $("#field_id").val();
...

if(assign_variable_name_to_field =="")
{
handle error here
}

(don't forget to handle errors also in the server side with php)

after everyting is good then here comes ajax

datastring = $("form_id").serialize();

$.ajax({
type:'post',
url:'url_of_your_php_file'
data: datastring,
datatype:'json',
...
success: function(msg){
if(msg.error==true)
{
show errors from server side without refreshing page
alert(msg.message)
//this will alert error message from php
}
else
{
show success message or redirect
alert(msg.message);
//this will alert success message from php
}

})

});
```

on php page

```
$variable = $_POST['field_name']; //don't use field_id if the field_id is different than field name

...

then use server side validation
if(!$variable)
{
$data['error']= true;
$data['message'] = "this field is required...blah";
echo json_encode($data);
}
else
{
after everything is good
do any crud or email sending 
and then
$data['error'] = "false";
$data['message'] = "thank you ....blah";
echo json_encode($data);
}
```